# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I'm trying to use UWSGI with a virtualenv. My app ini is:

```
[uwsgi]
dir             = /var/www/KRAKEN/public/xxx.me/appxx
chdir           = %(dir)
#master          = true
processes       = 1
socket          = /var/run/uwsgi/app/appxx/socket
chmod-socket    = 666
enable-threads  = true
vacuum          = true
plugin          = python34
virtualenv      = /home/gabriel/python_env/appxx/
wsgi-file       = app.py
mount           = /%dir=app.py
logto           = %(dir)/uwsgi.log
py-autoreload   = true
```

And get:

```
Set PythonHome to /home/gabriel/python_env/appxx
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
```

If i use the standard python version (2.7) by changing the plugin option in the ini, i get:

```
"no module named site".
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: You have specified a virtualenv, (`/home/gabriel/python_env/appxx/`).  Is it working correctly?  That error is often from a misconfigured PYTHONPATH or other site issues.

Comment: @StephenRauch hi! Yes, because the log output shows Python 3.4 which is consistent with the pyton version in the venv. The system default is 2.7.